# Averages of number in a file python

Tags: python, file, csv, average

I want to be able to open a file say "numbers.txt" in python, the file should contain numbers separated by commas. e.g.

```
1,2
6,4,7
4,5,6
```

I want to write a function that calculates the average of each line and then returns a list with each of the averages in it:

for example for the numbers above the function would return: [1.5,5.67,5]

```
def line_averages(filename):
    f = open(filename, "r")
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.close
    for line in lines:
       b = line.split(",")
```

This is my code so far, but i do not know how to take it further.

Comment: What is it that you have a problem with **specifically**?

Comment: Sounds very much like homework...

Comment: Careful: It's `f.close()`, not `f.close`.

Answer (score 3):

Use a [CSV reader](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) to input the data, then once you find the input, calculate the average and output it however you want. I'm only going to show the first bit, and some code that will print out the lines, I'll let you figure out from there how to do it. This code is factored for python 2.x, only the print should change to convert it to python 3.x.

```
import csv
filename='blah.csv'
with open(filename, 'rb') as csvfile:
     spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
     for row in spamreader:
          for value in row:
             print value
```

Edit: Having looked at what you have, you could make the following change:

```
def line_averages(filename):
    f = open(filename, "r")
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.close()
    for line in lines:
        b = line.split(",")
        for value in b:
            print value
```

Comment: In 3, you'd also need to change the `open` (`open(filename, newline='')` or suchlike.)

Comment: More elegant solution than F3AR3DLEGEND's, however I would be hesitant to introduce a python newbie to csv, especially when he can take a much more newb friendly approach.

Comment: @NlightNFotis: I wrote that solution before he had included any code, hence my edit to showing the next step to his code, as opposed to using the csvreader.

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto Oh, I'm sorry dude, I don't know I missed that. My eye fell on the `csv` :P

Answer (score 1):

You're off to a nice start, but not done yet.
An easier way (in my opinion) to read line per line of a file is:

```
def line_averages(fileName):
    line_avgs = []
    with open(fileName, 'r') as my_file:
        for line in my_file: # this will read the file line by line
            numbers = line.split(',')
            total = 0
            for num in numbers:
                total += int(num)
            my_avg = total / float(len(numbers)) # it must be a float so it returns a float
            line_avgs.append(my_avg)
    my_file.close()
    return line_avgs
```

Comment: This doesn't seem right.  `num` is a string, and your `my_avg` and `line_avgs` lines seem indented too far.  (I'd use a `sum`/genexp solution myself.)

Comment: Oh wow, didn't notice that. I was writing this quickly... Fixed that :P

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you were missing was the way to convert the strings to integers.
After that you just need to sum a divide, hope it helps.

```
def line_averages(filename):
    averages = []
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            numbers = [int(x) for x in line.split(',')]
            averages.append(sum(numbers) / float(len(numbers)))
    return averages
```

Answer (score 1):

may be this one will be hard to understand; but it will give you more insight.. .

text file:

```
1,2
6,4,7
4,5,6
4,9,9,9
```

average of per-line:::

```
In [177]: from __future__ import division

In [178]: f=open('test.txt',"r")

In [179]: [reduce(lambda x,y:(float(x)+float(y)), a.split(','))/len(a.split(',')) for a in f.readlines()]
Out[179]: [1.5, 5.666666666666667, 5.0, 7.75]

In [180]: f.close()
```